# GraalVM javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#loginAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace

Tags: javafx, fxml, gluon, graalvm

I'm running into an error running the native image produced by GraalVM (latest GraalVM built on JDK 11) via the Gluon Client Plugin.

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#loginAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script. fxml/LoginScreen.fxml:17

The compililation step works fine:

> mvn clean client:build

I see the binary in a folder called "*projectname*/target/client/x86_64-linux/*binaryname*"

The above error produced when I run the executable via "./*binaryname*"

The FXML line of code which its complaining about on line 17 is:

```
<Button fx:id="_loginButton" layoutX="516.0" layoutY="174.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginAction" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="Login" />
```

The backing code logic are as follows and marked with @FXML:

```
@FXML
void loginAction(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {

    LoginService loginservice = new LoginService(_usernameTextField.getText(), _passwordTextField.getText());
```

According to a JavaFX common errors list the problem is usually because the onAction event does not have the same name as specified in the controller - [Introduction to JavaFX
for Beginner Programmers - Pg 27](http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~rball/JavaBook/JavaFXBook.pdf) . However this is not the case, my program's naming is accurate. Using the JavaFX maven plugin (seperate from the GluonClient) using

> maven javafx:run

the program starts up correctly and works as expected. If I need to post more information, please let me know.

Here is my pom.xml (I only replaced only the name of my package below)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>com-demo-management-ui</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <client.plugin.version>0.1.26</client.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.demo.Launcher</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Uncomment to run on iOS: -->
                <!-- <target>ios</target> -->
                <mainClass>com.demo.Launcher</mainClass>
                <graalvmHome>/opt/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0-dev/</graalvmHome>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>gluon-releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And finally, here is the code where I set the controller (This is a method call, which I exchange my views as I need them, thus controller is passed as an argument in the creating a view):

```
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/"+baseController.getFxmlFile()));
        fxmlLoader.setController(baseController);
        Parent parent =  fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setFullScreen(fullScreen);
        stage.setMaximized(setMaximized);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

Comment: Check your import for `ActionEvent`.

Comment: The import is as follows: import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

Comment: And you set a controller (one way or another)?

Comment: Edit your question and post your pom (at least the part related to the client plugin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at `HelloFXML` sample in the [Client samples repository](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/tree/master/Maven/HelloFXML), you will see it uses the typical FXML file with a controller:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="pane" ... fx:controller="hellofx.HelloController">
```

In your case, you don't have the controller in the FXML file, but you provide it like:

```
fxmlLoader.setController(new hellofx.HelloController());
```

As you know, the `FXMLLoader` uses reflection to instantiate controller, controls and methods that are found while parsing the FXML file.

Either way, when you click the button that triggers the `loginAction` method, the FXMLLoader process that with this [call](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.fxml/src/main/java/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java#L1786):

```
MethodHelper.invoke(method, controller, params);
```

that uses reflection to handle such event.

With GraalVM, *reflection* is an issue, and you have to "help" it a little bit, by providing the classes/methods/fields that are going to be used reflectively at some point. Find more about it [here](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/REFLECTION.md).

The Client plugin already takes care for you of adding the JavaFX core classes and methods. You can see what's added in `target/client/x86_64-darwin/gvm/reflectionconfig-x86_64-darwin.json`.

However, your custom classes have to be added to that file. There are two ways you can do that:

- As in HelloFXML, via configuration/`reflectionList`, you will provide the custom class/es that will be used reflectively:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
          <reflectionList>
               <list>hellofx.HelloController</list>   <!-- your custom classes -->
          </reflectionList>
          <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This has the effect of opening all class methods/fields to reflection. You will see the result in the json file as:

```
  {
    "name" : "hellofx.HelloController",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true
  }
...
```

This should be enough to fix your issue.

- Via config files. As you can read in the Client's [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/#_jni_and_reflection), you can add a config file (`reflectionconfig.json`) to `META-INF/substrate/config` instead:

```
[
  {
    "name":"hellofx.HelloController",
    "methods":[{"name":"loginAction","parameterTypes":["javafx.event.ActionEvent"] }]
  }
]
```

This will fix it as well. Of course, it might require adding other methods you have in the controller too (like `initialize`).

This will open to reflection only this method, so it has a lower impact in memory footprint, and follows what the plugin does with the JavaFX core classes.

Comment: Adding my classes to the reflectionList solved my exact problem as in the post. My login screen is now showing and the FXML is loading as expected. I have to say that the entire application is not yet loading, as the native image seems to hang on the Apache HTTP Client which is part of my login process. Do I keep this thread open, or do I ask a new question if I can't resolve this particular issue? Thank you Jose for the clear answer, and for the quick response.

Comment: Glad it worked. It is best to create new posts for different issues.

Comment: @ReinhardBehrens It would be good that you could mark this answer as accepted, as it can be useful for others as well.